# all document.getElementById('') returning null

Tags: javascript, html

All `documentGetElementById` calls are returning a `null` value, I'm simply trying to log the id to the console, but I keep getting `null`.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
<body>      
    <section class="container">
      <form id="my-form">
        <h1>Add User</h1>
        <div class="msg"></div>
        <div>
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" id="email">
        </div>
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>

      <ul id="users"></ul>

      <!-- <ul class="items">
        <li class="item">Item 1</li>
        <li class="item">Item 2</li>
        <li class="item">Item 3</li>
      </ul> -->
    </section>
</body>

console.log(document.getElementById('my-form'));
console.log(document.getElementById('users'));
```

Comment: Assuming your console logs are inside script tags, the first should work fine. There's no element with an ID of `users` so that would return `null`.

Comment: Are you sure you are running your Javascript code *after* the body is loaded ?

Comment: the ul has an id of users and no im not using script tags im running the js in its own js page so it should be running after the body is loaded

Comment: @DemonKing ...and how are you including your js file in the above html?

Comment: <script src="index.js"></script>

Comment: Please include full code and file-tree, else, there's no way of telling the issue.

Comment: can you add `console.log("anything");` to your `index.js` file and see if it get printed?

Comment: Use the document.onload event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this. This will work fine. Only way its comming null if it run before the page is fully loaded. If you put the script at the end of the body, it will work fine.

```
<html>
<head>
    
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="poo">javascript practice</h1>   
    <section class="container">
      <form id="my-form">
        <h1>Add User</h1>
        <div class="msg"></div>
        <div>
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" id="email">
        </div>
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>

      <ul id="users"></ul>

      <!-- <ul class="items">
        <li class="item">Item 1</li>
        <li class="item">Item 2</li>
        <li class="item">Item 3</li>
      </ul> -->
    </section>
<script>
        console.log(document.getElementById('my-form'));
        console.log(document.getElementById('users'));
    </script>
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i have my script linked to the html via js page   <script src="index.js"></script>
so it should be working correctly right?

Comment: Put that under the body section, I mean replace my script code above with <script src="index.js"></script>, or you have to call that console.log on the body load event, just to make sure the body load before your javascript runs.

Comment: moving the src below the closing body tag worked thanks, i thought the js can only load before the body when using script tags, does this mean the script link should always be at the bottom before the closing body tag?

Comment: @DemonKing its best practive to put it under the body, that make sure it will run after the body is loaded. There are some performance benifit too. You can also put it in head, but you have to then use a load event on body or document, which will make sure to run the code when body or document loaded.